# Is it possible to hide the user password in Oracle JDBC diagnostic trace?

Tags: oracle, ojdbc

When enabling the Oracle JDBC diagnostic trace (using the ojdbc8_g.jar) the resulting trace output shows the connecting users password in clear text. Is it possible to configure the diagnostic capability such that the password is not logged?

Example output:

*`527       [10/29/19 14:00:09:770 AEST] 000001f1 id=00000000 oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource                            3 getPhysicalConnection 1FF949C5 Enter: {user=oracle_user, password=passw0rd, connection_url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.0.0.26:1521/TESTDB}`*

Answer (score 1):

Is is possible to hide the user password in Oracle JDBC diagnostic trace? Yes, but only by severely limiting what is put in the trace up to and including not putting the SQL text in the trace. Not saying disable tracing but restrict what to trace.

In the recent releases (18c or even earlier) the Oracle JDBC does not knowingly put a password in a trace file. **However, it does put passwords in trace files when the driver doesn't know that the data is a password.** The most obvious example is the SQL text. The driver puts the SQL text into a trace file in many places. But the SQL text can include a password: ALTER USER ... IDENTIFIED BY ... . The driver doesn't know that the SQL text includes a password. There are many other paths where passwords are added to trace files but the driver doesn't know the particular value is a password, eg character set conversion.

Comment: So are you saying that to not display the password in getPhysicalConnection as in the example, just don't enable "oracle.jdbc.pool" tracing?

Comment: Diagnostic Jars (ojdbc8_g.jar) are recommended to be used only in the test environment to debug an issue. It should not be used in the production environment.